# Is the list of badges standard?

Tags: support, badges, stack-exchange

Is the list of badges standard across all Stack Exchange sites? Or can one site have a different set of badges?

This question asked on behalf of http://rpg.stackexchange.com

Comment: Closing as dupe of a newer same question, with a better response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far all the websites - except area51 and stack apps - have the same badges.

Tag specific badges differ of course, but those are automated.

Answer (score 2):

StackApps also has a slightly different set of badges